# Allowed values shown as constant input in azure ml web service

Tags: web-services, post, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a web service using Azure ML and deployed it. It works, but when I hit the Test button to test the web service, I am not being able to enter a different set of input values in the screen which asks for input. See screenshot below. As you can see, it's not a textbox where I can enter values, but a dropdown where the values are the ones in my script.

[image]

Also, note how the instructions page shows allowed values as just those values
[image]

These values are from my initial script where I do the following

```
## ------- User-Defined Parameters ------ ##

IDinput<- data.frame(
GenderCD="M",
Age="8",
..,
..
)

# Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port
maml.mapOutputPort("IDinput");
```

I then have a script which reads these variables using POST as

```
# Map 1-based optional input ports to variables# Map 1-based optional input ports to variables
POST <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame

#getting data from POST
mytestrow = NULL
mytestrow$GenderCD=POST$GenderCD
mytestrow$Age=POST$Age

#perform logic and store in a data frame called outputdf

# Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port
maml.mapOutputPort("outputdf");
```

My overall architecture looks as
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tend toward Python in AzureML, but the concepts should still apply to R.

Categorical inputs are used to categorize data into several, well defined buckets. In the data you're passing in, it appears that you are restricting the allowable values, rather than providing default values, which seems to be your intent.

```
## ------- User-Defined Parameters ------ ##

IDinput<- data.frame(
GenderCD="M",
Age="8",
..,
..
)
```

Can you pass in the allowed parameters in a tuple-like construct?

```
GenderCD = c("M","F")
Age = c(1,2,3,4,5,...,110,111,112)
...
IDinput<- data.frame(GenderCD,Age,...,other)
```